# QuestPDF: Changing max number of pages

Tags: c#, pdf, report

I'm migrating an existing report from iText to QuestPDF, and I am new to both of the packages.

I'm not finding much help online for questions about QuestPDF in C#. So, here's one:

- My report is longer than 250 pages, which is the default max. Based on their API, I need to modify `DocumentMetadata.DocumentLayoutExceptionThreshold` but can't figure out how to do that. Nothing I've tried to change the value is effective. No errors, but the value doesn't change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! LOTS to learn!

Thanks in advance!

Jim

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *"because iText changed their licensing terms from v5 to v7"* - no, not really. The relevant change was from v4 to v5.

Comment: @mkl - May be correct, but not actually helpful.

Comment: On the contrary, if a license terms switch from iText v5 to iText v7 caused you to start migrating, the information that there was no relevant switch would allow you to stop migrating. ;) Seriously, though, paragraphs like your first one are an invitation to start irrelevant comments.

Answer (score 4):

in case you haven't already fixed that, you can change the value with this line:

```
QuestPDF.Settings.DocumentLayoutExceptionThreshold = 1000;
```

Good luck!

Comment: [Link to relevant doc](https://www.questpdf.com/concepts/settings.html#maximum-document-length). It's recommended to configure these settings in your project startup, but it can be done anywhere.